# How do I make an R shiny datatable that is coloured row by row depending on the values in the cells?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

**The Situation**:

The following code produces a datatable with coloured cells as a shiny output. The cells are coloured in a way that the cell with the highest value ***of ALL cells*** in the table is the most red.

```
# __________  Minimal Example  ________________
# ---------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(DT)

  shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
        )
      )
    ),


    server = function(input, output) {

   output$mytable=DT::renderDataTable({
    irisNumbersOnly=iris[c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
    brks <- quantile(irisNumbersOnly, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
    clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
    {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}
    iriswithcolorDT=datatable(iris)%>%
      formatStyle(names(irisNumbersOnly), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
    return(iriswithcolorDT)

  })

    }
  )
```

**The Aim**:

I would like to have a datatable that is coloured row by row. I do not want the cell with the ***highest value of alls cells*** in the table to be the most red. Instead I want the cell with the ***highest value in the row*** to be the most red.

**The Question:**

What do I need to change the above code to in order to achieve this aim?

Comment: Is it fine if only one cell (the row max is highlighted) ?

Comment: @amrrs Unfortunately, all cells in the row must be coloured according to their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks easy to do with '[formattable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html)'.

```
library(formattable)
table <- formattable(iris, lapply(1:nrow(iris), function(row) {
  area(row) ~ color_tile("transparent", "red")
}))
as.datatable(table)
```

[image]

Comment: For completeness: Add this line to the server function:   'output$tableJ=renderDataTable({as.datatable(formattable(iris[1:13,], lapply(1:nrow(iris[1:13,]), function(row) {  area(row) ~ color_tile("transparent", "orange") } )))})' and add this line to the UI-function: 'DT::dataTableOutput("tableJ")'